I am facing ImportError: cannot import name 'LlamaCPP' from 'llama_index.llms' (unknown location) while implementing this
I am facing ImportError: cannot import name 'LlamaCPP' from 'llama_index.llms' (unknown location) while implementing
and ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.llms.llama_utils' this
while implementing this:
import torch

#from llama_index.llms import LlamaCPP
from llama_index.llms.llama_utils import messages_to_prompt, completion_to_prompt
llm = LlamaCPP(
    
    model_url='https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1-GGUF/resolve/main/mistral-7b-instruct-v0.1.Q4_K_M.gguf',
    # optionally, you can set the path to a pre-downloaded model instead of model_url
    model_path=None,
    temperature=0.1,
    max_new_tokens=256,
    # llama2 has a context window of 4096 tokens, but we set it lower to allow for some wiggle room
    context_window=3900,
    # kwargs to pass to __call__()
    generate_kwargs={},
    # kwargs to pass to __init__()
    # set to at least 1 to use GPU
    model_kwargs={"n_gpu_layers": -1},
    # transform inputs into Llama2 format
    messages_to_prompt=messages_to_prompt,
    completion_to_prompt=completion_to_prompt,
    verbose=True,
)

PDF chat bot I am creating

it seems like your imports are depreciated
try using
from llama_index.llms.llama_cpp.llama_utils import messages_to_prompt, completion_to_prompt

also install c dependencies for llama.cpp

The imports you are using are depreciated.
Here are the updated versions:
First, install the embeddings:
!pip install llama-index-embeddings-huggingface
!pip install llama-index-llms-llama-cpp

Next:
Use llama_index.core instead of llama_index
Use llama_index.llms.llama_cpp.llama_utils instead of llama_index.llms.llama_utils 

Your entire code should be as follows:
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader, VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.llms.llama_cpp import LlamaCPP
from llama_index.llms.llama_cpp.llama_utils import (messages_to_prompt,completion_to_prompt,)

